# Unable to recognize syntax error

Tags: perl, syntax

My code, taken almost out of the module cpan page:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Curl;
my $lwpcurl = LWP::Curl->new();
my $referer = 'http://www.example.com/';
my $post_url = 'https://example';
my $key='363073020844984X3v2';
my $hash='73wKwB802h8y26VrmyGD4TIqXSnsV7u39DDOOCd82578t9c92paeBABnMH0ahzp6lzH';
my $action='boot';  # ACTION="info&ipaddr=true&mem=true&hdd=true&bw=true"
my $hash_form = { 
    'KEY' => $key,
    'HASH' => $hash,
    'action' => $action,
}
my $content = $lwpcurl->post($post_url, $hash_form, $referer); 
print $content;
```

I'm getting an odd syntax error:

```
syntax error at soluscontrol.pl line 16, near "my "
Global symbol "$content" requires explicit package name at /root/bash-advanced-scripts/soluscontrol.pl line 16.
Global symbol "$hash_form" requires explicit package name at /root/bash-advanced-scripts/soluscontrol.pl line 16.
Global symbol "$content" requires explicit package name at /root/bash-advanced-scripts/soluscontrol.pl line 17.
Execution of /root/bash-advanced-scripts/soluscontrol.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I'm unable to recognize where the error is coming from.

Comment: You miss a ';'  at end of hash declaration.`my $hash_form = { 
    'KEY' => $key,
    'HASH' => $hash,
    'action' => $action,
}
`

Comment: Tip: If perl complains about something that looks correct, look at the line above it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement starting on line 10 is missing its terminating semi-colon.

```
my $hash_form = { 
    'KEY' => $key,
    'HASH' => $hash,
    'action' => $action,
}
```

should be

```
my $hash_form = { 
    'KEY' => $key,
    'HASH' => $hash,
    'action' => $action,
};
```